# How to export Table Schema with Column name and other details into Excel file from SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: How I want my export format]

I want to export these details of a table into excel file using SQL Developer.

I can only find export data & DDL scripts which the other person won't understand or not interested in looking at such scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are on the Columns tab of a table, click on any column_name value. Press CTRL + A to select the entire table, then press CTRL + SHIFT + C to copy all the value with the header.
Open a new Excel sheet and paste the content of the clipboard.

If you don't want the header, use the standard CTRL + C instead of CTRL + SHIFT + C.

Comment: @ShabbirEssaji, instead of thanking in a comment, show your appreciation by marking the answer as correct. (The green check mark should appear under the up/down arrows then.)

Comment: Dont know why some one downvoted the Question . It really helps one to give schema to someone who doesnt have to do anything with DB & just need the architecture of where's data is stored

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

You can use this script to generate the values as you wish and then copy them all to an excel sheet.

```
SELECT tbl.NAME              AS TableName,
       col.NAME              AS ColumnName,
       typ.NAME              AS DataType,
       --,col.is_nullable as Nullable
       --,col.is_identity as PK
       
       Concat(CASE
                WHEN col.is_identity = 1 THEN 'Pk,'
                ELSE ''
              END, CASE
                     WHEN fk.constraint_column_id = 1 THEN 'Fk,'
                     ELSE ''
                   END, CASE
                          WHEN col.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'null'
                          ELSE 'not null'
                        END) AS Property
--, fk.*, col.* , typ.*
FROM   sys.columns AS col
       INNER JOIN sys.types typ
               ON typ.user_type_id = col.user_type_id
       INNER JOIN sys.tables AS tbl
               ON tbl.object_id = col.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
               ON s.schema_id = tbl.schema_id
       LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk
              ON fk.parent_object_id = col.object_id
                 AND fk.parent_column_id = col.column_id
WHERE  tbl.NAME != '__EFMigrationsHistory'
ORDER  BY tbl.NAME
```

**Step 2 : Copying**

1. `left-click` on the green tick to select all.
2. press `ctrl+c` to copy and then paste using `ctrl+v`

[image]